# After installed Spring Security Plugin, my grails cannot start

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using Grails 2.4.2. I was trying to create login page, but after install a plugin called spring security, my grails start having errors:

```
| Error 2017-03-03 17:39:36,985 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: feedbackdemo.type
Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: feedbackdemo.type
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: feedbackdemo.type
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="grailsApplication" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean">
    <description>Grails application factory bean</description>
    <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="pluginManager" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean">
    <description>A bean that manages Grails plugins</description>
    <property name="grailsDescriptor" value="/WEB-INF/grails.xml" />
    <property name="application" ref="grailsApplication" />
</bean>

<bean id="grailsConfigurator" class="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="grailsApplication" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="pluginManager" ref="pluginManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="characterEncodingFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter">
    <property name="encoding">
        <value>utf-8</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
```

I don't know what is the problem, even though I remove the Spring Security it still come out with this error, anybody mind to share their way to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with 'grailsApplication' bean creation due to class not found exception. And your 'grailsApplication' points to grails.xml.

Manual bean definition in xml is too complicated and unneeded because grails does it for you.

I would recommend you to redesign the app as shown here: http://docs.grails.org/2.4.2/guide/single.html#gettingStarted

Comment: I don't want to redesign the app as it is trouble for me, anyway my grails have problem now because of grails command not found issue.

Comment: Well it works after I recreated, even though it is troubling.

Comment: Anyway the xml configuration is difficult to support. I'm glad that everything works for you now.